# PHP Increment in For-each Works on Buttons Labels but not on Posted URL

Tags: php, html, foreach

I'm creating a web page that reads and displays files from a directory within the website, I'm using a for-each loop to iterate through the files and give the specific names based off the increment. When the user clicks the specific button I wan't my form to pass the specific increment so I know which file to use when it goes to the next page. The buttons display the increment as expected but the url always passes "1" as the value and I really dont know why, I attached a picture to show the buttons working[image: Buttons Showing] but the link always becomes http://Mywebsite.com/AuthorizeCapabilityRequest.php?1

```
<?php

$images = glob($directory . "*.*");
 echo "<div class='col-md-12' align='center'><div class='col-md-10'>
       <table class='table table-bordered table-striped'>
      <tr>
        <th width='65%'>Filename</th>
        <th width='20%'>Edit</th>
        <th width='15%'>Refer</th>
      </tr>";
    $dir = "Capability_Request/*";
    $zed = 1;


    foreach(glob($dir) as $file)
    {

        $base = basename($file);

        echo "<tr><td>";
        if(!is_dir($file)) { echo basename($file);}
        echo "</td><td><button type='button' class='btn btn-primary btn- 
             small' data-toggle='modal' data-target='#exampleModal$zed'>
          $zed

        </button> </td><td>

        <!-- Button trigger modal -->
        <button type='button' class='btn btn-primary' data-toggle='modal' 
         data-target='#exampleModalCenter'>
          $zed
        </button>

        <!-- Modal -->
        <div class='modal fade' id='exampleModalCenter' tabindex='-1' 
           role='dialog' aria-labelledby='exampleModalCenterTitle' aria- 
          hidden='true'>
          <div class='modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered' role='document'>
            <div class='modal-content'>
              <div class='modal-header'>
                <h5 class='modal-title' id='exampleModalLongTitle'>Refer 
                  Capability to UNF</h5>
                <button type='button' class='close' data-dismiss='modal' 
                aria-label='Close'>
                  <span aria-hidden='true'>&times;</span>
                </button>
              </div>
              <div class='modal-body'>";



                $url = "AuthorizeCapabilityRequest.php?".$zed;
                echo "<form action='$url' method='post'>";                  

                echo "<h6>If you would like to refer the capability to the 
                     UNF, and accept the capability request, select this 
                     button:</h6>";

                echo "<input class='btn btn-success btn-block' type='submit' 
                    value='Submit'>";
                echo "<hr>";
                echo "<h6>If you would like to refer the capability to the 
                      UNF, but deny the capability request, select this 
                      button:</h6>";
                echo "<button type='button' class='btn btn-warning btn- 
                      block'>Refer</button>";
                echo "<hr>";
                echo "<h6>If you would like to deny the capability referral 
                     to the UNF, select this button:</h6>";
                echo "<button type='button' class='btn btn-danger btn- 
                    block'>Deny</button>";
                echo "<div class='modal-footer'>";

                echo "<button type='button' class='btn btn-secondary' data- 
                    dismiss='modal'>Cancel</button>";

              echo "</form>";
              echo "</div>";                  
            echo "</div>";
          echo "</div>";
        echo "</div>";
    echo "</td></tr>";

    $zed++;             
    }       
echo "</table></div></div>";
```

Comment: So what happens if somone creates another file in that folder between you showing the first page and then trying to get the right file in the second script? ___Total Mahem or total rethink___

Comment: No, sorry for the bad explanation. The files are already in the folder, when the user clicks "refer to" it takes them to another web page in which it displays the contents. I'm trying to pass the id (ie. the incriment) in the url so I can just loop through the directory and chose the file at the selected id. But the increment in the url is always "1"

Comment: Yet the buttons manage to display the increment properly (I did this as a test)

Comment: Hi, and I am saying that that is not a very good idea. The only thing that is pretty much guaranteed not to change is the filename

Comment: I'm just trying to pass the increment in the url but its not working and I have no clue why. I understand it might not be the best way but I cant think of a better way to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ID's of elements have to be unique. Currently you give your 'modal div' the same ID for every iteration in

```
<div class='modal fade' id='exampleModalCenter' tabindex='-1' 
role='dialog' aria-labelledby='exampleModalCenterTitle' aria-hidden='true'>
```

So what you should do are a few things: make sure the IDs are all unique (use your `$zed`variable) and then have your `data-target` correspond to that unique ID (again with your `$zed` variable).

EDIT: here's an example of how this would work:

```
<button type="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal<?php echo $zed; ?>">
your button
</button>

<div class="modal" id="exampleModal<?php echo $zed; ?>">
your modal
</div>
```

Comment: I was doing this exact thing on my web page not linked to this one. I cant believe I didnt think to do that here. Thanks so much this worked. If i had enough rep points to up vote your reply I would, but alas, I dont. Thanks this worked for me!

Comment: Glad I could help out! You were already almost there, just missed this bit.